# Update Command Work but row not update in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

my update Command is work but not row updated,other command like select or delete work Properly
please help me Where I was wrong
I use visual stadio2015 and ms office 2010

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessDB"].ConnectionString);
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

command.CommandText = "Update  Party  Set  Address=@address, PhoneNumber=@phone, FaxNumber=@fax, UniqueNumber=@unique where PartyID=@id";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", this.partyID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", this.address);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", this.phoneNumber);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(faxNumber))
{
    faxNumber = string.Empty;
}

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", this.faxNumber);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unique", this.uniqueNumber);

connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: When using OleDb the order of the parameters is critical, the statement must match the order in the parameters list. Under the covers the names of the parameters mean nothing, only the order matters. Names are only there for your convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using OleDb (with Access) the order of the parameters is critical, the statement must match the order in the parameters list. Under the covers the names of the parameters mean nothing, only the order matters. Names are only there for your convenience.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessDB"].ConnectionString))
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
{
    command.Connection = connection;

    //                                                 1st                   2nd               3rd                4th                   5th
    command.CommandText = "Update  Party  Set  Address=@address, PhoneNumber=@phone, FaxNumber=@fax, UniqueNumber=@unique WHERE PartyID=@id";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", this.address); // 1st
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", this.phoneNumber); // 2nd
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(faxNumber))
    {
        faxNumber = string.Empty;
    }

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", this.faxNumber); // 3rd
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unique", this.uniqueNumber); //4th
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", this.partyID); // 5th

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

---

Also do use `using` blocks on the instances where the Type implements `IDisposable`. It ensures that resources are always released even if an Exception is thrown.

Finally do not use `AddWithValue`. Instead you `command.Parameters.Add`, example: `command.Parameters.Add("@pname", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = "someValue";`. See also [AddWithValue is Evil - Dan Guzman](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already? - Joel Coehoorn](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). I did *not* include this in the code above.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Hilex - glad to help.